# How to align text to start where other text starts

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Right now the text is like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing
                 elit vitae orci elementum dictum
```

I want to be like that:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing
elit vitae orci elementum dictum
```

I want the second text line to start where the first line starts.
the first text line is aligned to right.

Comment: What is your HTML structure? Does the text wrap because of its container's width or is each line a separate HTML element? Please also include your current CSS so others can [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out. May be helpful

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing<br>
<span>elit vitae orci elementum dictum</span></p>

<style>
    p { float: right; }
    span { float: left; }
</style>
```

Comment: For future readers, what was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way of doing it is using 2 p tags
In HTML:

```
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="author">Author</p>
```

In Css:

```
.text{
  font-size: 15px;
}
.author{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grey;
}
```

Comment: if this method solved your problem or is helpful, kindly mark tick, it motivates others to answer more questions